# How to retrieve all Elements from XML file using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, http

I am trying to retrieve all elements from an XML file, but I just can reach one, is there any way I can retrieve all?

```
HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream())))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    #region Get Credit Score
                    //if (reader.ReadToDescendant("results"))

                    if (reader.ReadToDescendant("ssnMatchIndicator"))
                    {
                        string ssnMatchIndicator = reader.Value;
                    }

                    if (reader.ReadToDescendant("fileHitIndicator"))
                    {
                        reader.Read();//this moves reader to next node which is text 
                        result = reader.Value; //this might give value than 
                        Res.Response = true;
                        Res.SocialSecurityScore = result.ToString();
                        //break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Res.Response = false;
                        Res.SocialSecurityScore = "Your credit score might not be available. Please contact support";
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region Get fileHitIndicator
                    if (reader.ReadToDescendant("fileHitIndicator"))
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        Res.fileHitIndicator = reader.Value;
                        //break;
                    }
                    #endregion
                }
            }
```

Can somebody help me out with this issue?
I am also using **objResponse.GetResponseStream()** because the XML comes from a response from server.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you able to read the entire response into an `XDocument`? LINQ to XML is *much* simpler to use than `XmlReader`.

Comment: Not sure how to do it.

Comment: Well you can load it easily enough with `XDocument.Load`, assuming the document will be small enough. The main reason to use `XmlReader` is if you have a potentially *huge* document that you don't want to load into memory.

Comment: I don't use XDocument.Load, however I've tried and the catch statement displayed this error: **Non white space characters cannot be added to content**

Comment: That's suggests you're getting invalid XML. I suggest you save a response locally as a file just for development purposes - then you can write a simple console app which opens the file as a stream instead of doing it all in a web environment.

Comment: But it is weird because when I use **reader.ReadToDescendant("fileHitIndicator")** to get one value from the entire XML is retrieves the info correctly. The XML file starts with **<document xmlns="http://www.transunion.com/namespace">response</document>
<version xmlns="http://www.transunion.com/namespace">2.21</version>**

Comment: That means the document was okay *that far*. Perhaps there's extra content at the end, for example. If you download the data and look at it in an editor, you'll be in a much better position to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
        XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
        XmlNodeList xmlnode ;
        int i = 0;
        string str = null;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("product.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        xmldoc.Load(fs);
        xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Product");
        for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim();
            str = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim() + "  " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim() + "  " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim();
            MessageBox.Show (str);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly!! You saved my ass!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why what you're doing is not working, but I wouldn't use that method.  I've found the following to work well. Whether you're getting the xml from a stream, just put it into a string and bang...

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sourcepath);
string xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNodeList list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("*");
foreach (XmlNode nd in list)
{
    switch (nd.Name)
    {
        case "ContactID":
            var ContactIdent = nd.InnerText;
            break;
        case "ContactName":
            var ContactName = nd.InnerText;
            break;
    }
}
```

To capture what is between the Xml tags, if there are no child Xml tags, use the InnerText property, e.g. `XmlNode.InnerText`. To capture what is between the quotes in the nodes' attributes, use `XmlAttribute.Value`.

As for iterating through the attributes, if one of your nodes has attributes, such as the elements "Name", "SpectralType" and "Orbit" in the Xml here:

```
<System>
  <Star Name="Epsilon Eridani" SpectralType="K2v">
    <Planets>
      <Planet Orbit="1">Bill</Planet>
      <Planet Orbit="2">Moira</Planet>
    </Planets>
  </Star>
</System>
```

Detect them using the Attributes property, and iterate through them as shown:

```
if (nd.Attributes.Count > 0)
{
    XmlAttributeCollection coll = nd.Attributes;
    foreach (XmlAttribute cn in coll)
    {
        switch (cn.Name)
        {
            case "Name":
                thisStar.Name = cn.Value;
                break;
            case "SpectralType":
                thisStar.SpectralClass = cn.Value;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You might find some more useful information [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This works perfectly, however I am not 100% sure how to capture what it is he tag **<ssnMatchIndicator>exact</ssnMatchIndicator>** for example in this case the **exact**

Comment: @LanshoreDev, see the additional information I've added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help.